# Cacti per-process monitoring

Tags: monitoring, cacti

Are there any Cacti plugins that lets you monitor per-process CPU/memory/IO, etc., similar to what Perfmon provides on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

None that I'm aware of - Have you tried [looking through the Cacti forums](http://forums.cacti.net/) though? That's probably the best place to find new templates, etc.

Writing this would probably not be difficult (use the basic server CPU/Memory plugin as a model, but feed it from either the SNMP process table or a local script).

Comment: I do not think this is exposed trough SNMP. May be it is implemented with an agent like nrpe.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici Memory and CPU information is exposed under the Host-Resources MIB (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfMem & HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfCPU) -- I/O information would require a local script or some customization to the SNMP Daemon.

Comment: Thank you, @voretaq7, I did not know about those MIBs. I/O I think it is exposed trough WMI.

Comment: If you're on a Windows host WMI is the way to go all around (I don't know for sure if the Windows SNMP daemon even exposes the PerfMem and PerfCPU fields in its process list, but even if it did you can get the other information through WMI as well so it's one place to look instead of two)

Comment: You can use WMI in other OSes too. Look for DCOM connectors in Python and Java. OpenNMS is using the Java one. And for Nagios it is a Python plugin that is using DCOM/WMI.

Comment: I was referring to monitoring a Windows **host** - you wouldn't try to monitor a unix box using WMI.

Comment: You can monitor a Windows host trough WMI from a Linux box. And WMI/WBEM is used by ESXi, which is not a Windows.